# VBA - put values from 2D array to 2 or more cells

Tags: arrays, vba

I'm trying to figure out how to put values from a [N x 2] matrix to cells on the same row on a different worksheet.

The matrix, which changes, is something like:

```
1 0
1 2
1 3
2 0
2 1
2 2
```

... so on.

On a different sheet, using the items in the matrix, I want to create a vector that omits the zero, such as:

```
   A   B
1  1   1
2  1   2
3  1   3
4  2   1
5  2   2
```

... so on.

I already have an array filled with the values from the matrix. I am having problems trying to extract values from the array.

Eventually, there will be certain criteria and some combinations, so # of columns and rows will increase. So, I need to do this in VBA. Can anyone guide me in the right direction or provide some example code that I can reference?

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 0):

A sample for your reference

```
Sub testArr()
    'Declare a 4-by-2 matrix
    Dim Data(3, 1) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(Data, 1)
        For j = 0 To UBound(Data, 2)
            Data(i, j) = Int((10 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
        Next j
    Next i
    'You extract a value from the array like this
    MsgBox "data(2,1) = " & Data(2, 1)
End Sub
```